# Ubuntu 14.04 GRE tunnnel Open vSwitch 2.01

Tags: 14.04, tunnel

I installed the 2.0.1 openswitch version included with the Ubuntu 14.04 distribution.

I set up a simple gee tunnel and containers are pinging each other but any data flux is blocked.

This is the ovs-vswitchd.log on the machine trying to pull the data:

```
2014-05-18T21:54:30.974Z|00936|bridge|INFO|bridge br0: added interface br0 on port 65534
2014-05-18T21:54:30.975Z|00937|bridge|INFO|bridge br0: using datapath ID 000036aea2271f4d
2014-05-18T21:54:30.975Z|00938|connmgr|INFO|br0: added service controller "punix:/var/run/openvswitch/br0.mgmt"
2014-05-18T22:00:31.421Z|00939|bridge|INFO|bridge br0: added interface gre0 on port 1
2014-05-18T22:01:54.057Z|00940|bridge|INFO|bridge br0: added interface pl17753eth1 on port 2
2014-05-19T00:02:08.362Z|00941|netdev_linux|WARN|Dropped 3 log messages in last 7743 seconds (most recently, 7738 seconds ago) due to excessive rate
2014-05-19T00:02:08.362Z|00942|netdev_linux|WARN|ethtool command ETHTOOL_GSET on network device pl17753eth1 failed: No such device
2014-05-19T00:02:08.376Z|00943|ofproto|WARN|Dropped 37 log messages in last 7767 seconds (most recently, 7736 seconds ago) due to excessive rate
2014-05-19T00:02:08.376Z|00944|ofproto|WARN|br0: cannot get STP status on nonexistent port 2
2014-05-19T00:02:08.477Z|00945|ofproto|WARN|br0: cannot get STP status on nonexistent port 2
2014-05-19T00:02:08.634Z|00946|ofproto|WARN|br0: cannot get STP status on nonexistent port 2
2014-05-19T00:02:09.635Z|00947|ofproto|WARN|br0: cannot get STP status on nonexistent port 2
2014-05-19T00:02:10.636Z|00948|ofproto|WARN|br0: cannot get STP status on nonexistent port 2
2014-05-19T00:02:12.014Z|00949|netdev_linux|WARN|pl17753eth1: obtaining netdev stats via vport failed (No such device)
2014-05-19T00:02:12.014Z|00950|netdev_linux|WARN|ioctl(SIOCGIFINDEX) on pl17753eth1 device failed: No such device
2014-05-19T00:02:12.014Z|00951|netdev_linux|WARN|pl17753eth1: linux-sys get stats failed 19
2014-05-19T00:02:12.014Z|00952|netdev_linux|WARN|ethtool command ETHTOOL_GDRVINFO on network device pl17753eth1 failed: No such device
2014-05-19T00:02:12.014Z|00953|netdev_linux|WARN|ethtool command ETHTOOL_GSET on network device pl17753eth1 failed: No such device
2014-05-19T00:02:12.014Z|00954|netdev_linux|INFO|ioctl(SIOCGIFHWADDR) on pl17753eth1 device failed: No such device
```

This is the output of the ovs-vsctl show command on server one (10.1.1.253)

```
d7c6fea8-84b5-4be3-a698-a8e61745694c
    Bridge "br0"
        Port "gre0"
            Interface "gre0"
                type: gre
                options: {remote_ip="10.1.1.254"}
        Port "pl11394eth1"
            Interface "pl11394eth1"
        Port "br0"
            Interface "br0"
                type: internal
    ovs_version: “2.0.1"
```

and on server two (10.1.1.254)

```
e1e27383-c41e-45ac-aa1e-db835cc47388
    Bridge "br0"
        Port "gre0"
            Interface "gre0"
                type: gre
                options: {remote_ip="10.1.1.253"}
        Port "pl17753eth1"
            Interface "pl17753eth1"
        Port "br0"
            Interface "br0"
                type: internal
    ovs_version: "2.0.1"
```

Tunnel was working with same configuration Ubuntu 12.04 and Open vSwitch 2.1.2

What can be the issue?